# Pandas multi-indexing by grouping some of the two-columns and keeping other intact

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with some columns, I like to group some columns together, like group x and y means under mean, x and y variances under varinaces and so on.

The problem set-up is given below:

```
data = """
xbar    ybar    sx2 sy2 sp2 margin_err  ci_low  ci_high
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
0.750000    0.083333    0.750000    0.083333    0.416667    0.452507    0.21    1.12
0.166667    0.166667    0.333333    0.333333    0.333333    0.404735    -0.40   0.40
0.083333    0.500000    0.083333    0.636364    0.359848    0.420524    -0.84   0.00
0.166667    0.583333    0.333333    0.992424    0.662879    0.570753    -0.99   0.15
1.833333    1.250000    1.606061    0.931818    1.268939    0.789681    -0.21   1.37
1.250000    1.583333    2.022727    2.265152    2.143939    1.026449    -1.36   0.69
3.250000    5.333333    4.931818    16.060606   10.496212   2.271159    -4.35   0.19
6.083333    7.333333    12.265152   12.242424   12.253788   2.453954    -3.70   1.20
8.083333    6.666667    7.719697    4.969697    6.344697    1.765780    -0.35   3.18
3.166667    3.250000    5.060606    6.568182    5.814394    1.690376    -1.77   1.61
2.500000    1.916667    1.545455    3.719697    2.632576    1.137422    -0.55   1.72
0.833333    0.750000    0.696970    1.113636    0.905303    0.667004    -0.58   0.75
1.250000    0.500000    1.659091    0.636364    1.147727    0.751018    -0.00   1.50
0.166667    0.500000    0.333333    2.090909    1.212121    0.771799    -1.11   0.44
""";

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.lstrip().strip()),sep=r'\s+')
df
```

The desired output is something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKXp4.jpg

**Desired Output**

```
Mean            Variance Pooled_variance Margin_of_error 90%_CI
xbar    ybar    sx2 sy2 sp2 margin_err  ci_low  ci_high
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
0.750000    0.083333    0.750000    0.083333    0.416667    0.452507    0.21    1.12
```

My attempt:

```
df.columns = ['Mean_GER1','Mean_GER2','Var_GER1','Var_GER2','Var_pooled','Margin_of_error','CI_90_low','CI_90_high']
df
```

How to get the multi-index columns for this dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at Pandas Multi-indexing tutorials and came up with this solution:

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Mean', 'x'), ('Mean', 'y'), ('Sample_Variance', 'x'), ('Sample_Variance', 'y'),('Pooled_Var',''), ('Margin_of_Err',''),('95% CI','low'),('95% CI','high')])

pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=mi)
```

Result:

```
         Mean                 Sample_Variance      Pooled_Var Margin_of_Err 95% CI
    x           y               x          y                                low   high
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
1   0.750000    0.083333    0.750000    0.083333    0.416667    0.452507    0.21    1.12
2   0.166667    0.166667    0.333333    0.333333    0.333333    0.404735    -0.40   0.40
3   0.083333    0.500000    0.083333    0.636364    0.359848    0.420524    -0.84   0.00
4   0.166667    0.583333    0.333333    0.992424    0.662879    0.570753    -0.99   0.15
5   1.833333    1.250000    1.606061    0.931818    1.268939    0.789681    -0.21   1.37
6   1.250000    1.583333    2.022727    2.265152    2.143939    1.026449    -1.36   0.69
7   3.250000    5.333333    4.931818    16.060606   10.496212   2.271159    -4.35   0.19
8   6.083333    7.333333    12.265152   12.242424   12.253788   2.453954    -3.70   1.20
9   8.083333    6.666667    7.719697    4.969697    6.344697    1.765780    -0.35   3.18
10  3.166667    3.250000    5.060606    6.568182    5.814394    1.690376    -1.77   1.61
11  2.500000    1.916667    1.545455    3.719697    2.632576    1.137422    -0.55   1.72
12  0.833333    0.750000    0.696970    1.113636    0.905303    0.667004    -0.58   0.75
13  1.250000    0.500000    1.659091    0.636364    1.147727    0.751018    -0.00   1.50
14  0.166667    0.500000    0.333333    2.090909    1.212121    0.771799    -1.11   0.44
```